# Why can't I log `process.env` in my bundled code with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm adding those environment variables to my bundle using `Dotenv` and `DefinePlugin()`.

**webpack.config.js**

```
new Dotenv(),
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env.TEST_ENV": JSON.stringify("xxx")
}),
```

`Dotenv` loads a `.env` file with a bunch of environment variables. It's all working fine.

Webpack also injects by default `NODE_ENV` based on the `mode` you set in the
`webpack.config.js`.

This is working fine and I'm able to read both `NODE_ENV` and `TEST_ENV` from my compiled and bundled code.

**index.js**

```
const { NODE_ENV, TEST_ENV } = process.env;

console.log(`process.env: ${JSON.stringify(process.env)}`);
console.log(`NODE_ENV: ${JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV)}`);
console.log(`TEST_ENV: ${JSON.stringify(TEST_ENV)}`);
```

[image]

I can successfully access and log both variables `NODE_ENV` and `TEST_ENV` from the `process.env` object, as you can see from the image above.

But when I try to log `process.env` itself, it logs an empty object `{}`, as you can also see from the picture.

Why is that? Why can't I log `process.env` just like I did with its properties `NODE_ENV` and `TEST_ENV`?

Comment: The properties might not be enumerable? Please post the transpiled output, it should become clear then.

Comment: I didn't find the location of this part of the code in my app's bundle. I'll try to test it later with minimal functionality to see how webpack implements this `process.env` object.

Comment: Alternatively just `console.log(process.env)` (without json-stringifying it) or assign it to a global variable that allows further inspection in the devtools.

Comment: I tried. It logs `Object object`. How can I assign it to a global? Just `window.SOME_GLOBAL = process.env` ? Where do I inspect it?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

[image]

Given the fact that `DefinePlugin` does a **direct replacement** on your code, when you do this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env.SOME_VARIABLE": JSON.stringify("SOME_VALUE")
});
```

And you call it in your code like this:

**index.js**

```
const SOME_VARIABLE = process.env.SOME_VARIABLE;
```

Webpack will transpile it as:

```
const SOME_VARIABLE = "SOME_VALUE"
```

It completely replaces the `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE` for the string `"SOME_VALUE"`. That's also why you need the `JSON.stringify("SOME_VALUE")` call. Because otherwise you would get `const SOME_VARIABLE = SOME_VALUE`, without the string quotes, and you'll get the `SOME_VALUE is not defined` error.

That's why you can't log or destructure `process.env` in your bundled code.